# Can I use gcloud app deploy in a CI environment?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, continuous-integration, app-engine-flexible

I'm confused as to how I should deploy a Google AppEngine-based application (flexible environment) from CI. I thought I'd be able to just `gcloud app deploy` from the CI machine, but [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/testing-and-deploying-your-app) suggest otherwise:

> To programmatically deploy your apps, use the Admin API.

The [admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview), meanwhile, seems like a lot more work. For example, it puts the onus on me to build and push the Docker images, as well as create the `app.json` manifest.

I don't mind doing this if I have to, but can someone explain why I can't just `gcloud app deploy` from the CI host?

Comment: You *might* have some trouble authenticating in the non-interactive CI environment. Most likely you'll need a manual step at least once, the question is - will that be enough for all subsequent executions?

Comment: Never mind - it works with service accounts as well: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_application) that you linked, it also says that you can just use `gcloud app deploy`.

> Deploy your application to App Engine using the `gcloud app deploy` command. This command automatically builds a container image by using the Cloud Build service and then deploys that image to the App Engine flexible environment. The container will include any local modifications that you've made to the runtime image.

Comment: Sure, but my confusion is over their statement that the admin API should be used for "programmatic deployments". It makes me wonder whether using `gcloud app deploy` will lead to unforeseen problems.

Comment: The API *should* be more stable/reliable, the CLI intended for humans can change without warning and lead to breakages. CLI-based automation is almost always possible, but is typically much more fragile than an API-based one (which is I guess what they call programmatic)

Comment: @DanCornilescu That sounds reasonable. However, because the CLI does _so much more for you_ than the API, I think I'll just use it instead. Indeed, I've since found other people doing the same. For example, [here](https://medium.com/evenbit/an-easy-guide-to-automatically-deploy-your-google-app-engine-project-with-gitlab-ci-48cb84757125) and [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/continuous-integration-with-google-application-engine-and-travis-d822b751fb47)